# Is it possible to add hardcoded option/values in dropdownlist while retrieving a list from database ? MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code that can retrieve a list from database in dropdownlist. I want to add hardcoded value or option to this.

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.specimentype.Where(model => model.recordstatus == "active").ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.code.ToString(),
                Text = c.specimenType
            });

            ViewBag.specimentypelist = items;
```

View:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SpecimenType, new SelectList(ViewBag.specimentypelist, "Value", "Text", Model.SpecimenType), new { @class = "specimendropdown", @style = "height:27px; margin-left: 40px;" })
```

I want this to be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SpecimenType, new List<SelectListItem> { Text = "Horizontal", Value = "Horizontal" }, new SelectList(ViewBag.specimentypelist, "Value", "Text", Model.SpecimenType), new { @class = "specimendropdown", @style = "height:27px; margin-left: 40px;" })
```

Comment: You should be generating your `SelectList` in the controller, not in the view (and then you can add additional `SelectListItem` objects to it as required before passing it to the view). But your implementation makes no sense - what is the point of a disabled `<select>`? And if `specimentypelist` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, why are you creating another identical `SelectList` from it. And setting the last parameter (`Model.SpecimenType`) is not required - its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: Add a value in Controller to the ViewBag.specimentypeList

Comment: please see my update thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should move your list generation to the controller, like so for instance

```
      model.SelectListOptions= new List<SelectListItem>
            { new SelectListItem() { Text = "DatabaseOption1", Selected = true, Value = "1"}
             , new SelectListItem() { Text = "DatabaseOption2", Selected = false, Value = "2"}
             , new SelectListItem() { Text = "AddedOption1", Selected = false, Value = "3"} };
```

And in your view, you can now reference it like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SpecimenType, Model.SelectListOptions, null, new { @class = "specimendropdown", @style = "height:27px; margin-left: 40px;", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

**UPDATE**
To account for your database retrieval, there's not much you need to do.  You could add the SelectListItems to the list, like so:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.specimentype.Where(model => model.recordstatus == "active").ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = c.code.ToString(),
    Text = c.specimenType
}).ToList();   

items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "AddedOption1", Selected = false, Value = "3"});

ViewBag.specimentypelist = items;
```

Just convert the `IEnumerable` to a `List`, and use the Add() method to append your options to the list you retrieve from the database.

You can also use the `Insert` method if you want to put them in at a specific place.

Comment: but how can I retrieve the list from database by doing this ?